# Removing specific html cell borders using writeHTML in TCPDF

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to generate a certificate.

I want specific `<td>` cells to have no right border (this way I can make it appear as thought it is a merged cell, but still use the cell for positioning of data).

I am aware that TCPDF `writeHTML()` only parses certain bits of CSS, but I thought `border` was included.

The code works in principal ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ewg3p2h/1/)) but not in TCPDF.

Am I missing something or is there an alternative method? Other than giving each `<td>` it's own border for every cell.

Code:

```
$pdf->writeHTML("<style>
  table, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
  }
  
  .no-border-right {
    border-right: hidden;
  }
  
    
</style>
<table cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <td class="no-border-right"><b>6. Source of supply:</b><br>Generator</td>
        <td><b>Supply located at:</b><br> Some data</td>
        <td><b>7. Supply earthing arrangements:</b><br>Some data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>8. Protective devices at source of supply</b></td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
</table>", false);
```

Comment: It seems TCPDF still only supports some CSS rules, they even state it on their homepage (_"methods to publish some XHTML + CSS code ..."_). If possible I would recommend to switch to [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) as HTML to PDF conversion is its main purpose.

Comment: Borders are specifically listed as being supported, but i'm not sure "how deep" I can go. For example, it definitely accepts border colours and widths.